# data accumulation with csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Here's an sample csv file;

```
out_gate,in_gate,n_con
/a_a,b,1
/a_a,b,3
/a_b,a,2
/a_b,c,4
/a_c,a,5
/a_c,b,5
/a_c,b,3
/a_c,a,4
/a_d,c,2
/a_d,c,3
/a_d,b,2
```

and I am trying to match each data one by one and accumulate it so for example,
/a_a->b : 4  ,/a_b->a :2, /a_c->d: 0, /a_d->c: 5 and here's my code

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

with open("C:/Users/user/test1.txt") as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) >= 3:
            x,y,count = row
        d[x][y] += int(count)

keys = sorted(d)
for x in keys:
    print(x, [d[x][y] for y in keys])
```

and there comes the error saying that 'x' is not defined. (NameError: name 'x' is not defined , line 12)

My ultimate goal is to make it like this form(values are not correct);
so that I can convert it to excel file using csv writer directly.
How can I correct my current code?

```
    ,a,b,c,d
/a_a,0,1,1,1
/a_b,1,0,7,2
/a_c,1,6,0,3
/a_d,1,5,4,0
```

Comment: On what line is the error? Is it this one `d[x][y] += int(count)` ? Can you post the full trace?

Comment: Exactly. I just posted the error

Comment: Well then `len(row) >= 3` is evaluating to `False` and `x` is never being defined. Maybe you are missing an indent?

Comment: then if I erase the 10th line, there comes another error saying that there are no values to unpack.
and when i change the whole values of 1st column of given csv file to '/a_a' -> 'a' form, No error occurs and worked. So I guess it's not a matter of indent. thanks though

Comment: thanks for the notice! but same pblm still remains..

Comment: When you [caught the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspected/printed the data, did you find anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there might be some stylistic problems with your code, when I paste in the version you have listed currently, the dictionary-building part works fine for me.

What doesn't work is the printing part. You're trying to access the nested dictionaries using the keys of the top-level dictionary. When I change the print statements to:

```
keys = sorted(d)
for x in keys:
    child_keys = sorted(d[x])
    for y in child_keys:
        print(x, y, d[x][y])
```

And leave the rest of the code alone, I see the expected output:

```
('/a_a', 'b', 4)
('/a_b', 'a', 2)
('/a_b', 'c', 4)
('/a_c', 'a', 9)
('/a_c', 'b', 8)
('/a_d', 'b', 2)
('/a_d', 'c', 5)
```

Comment: thanks ! How can I add rows that are not considered as well when calculating??
(such as  ('/a_a', 'a',0) or ('/a_a','c',0) or ('/b_b','d',0))